# XSLT selecting descendants ignoring others

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I've looked at other solutions, but none have worked. I think what makes this tricky is the namespace node.
I want to grab all descendants (none.assigned and analgesic.adjuncts),  but ignore the atict:add
The root is gathered as a variable $storage from the input document.

```
<root xmlns:atict="http://www.arbortext.com/namespace/atict">
<t.classification>
<none.assigned/><atict:add user="RFA" time="1646751859"><analgesic.adjuncts/></atict:add></t.classification>
</root>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/" priority="10">
        <xsl:variable name="sourceAssetXml">
            <xsl:copy-of select="/asset"/>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:variable name="storage">
            <xsl:copy-of select="doc(concat('censhare:///service/assets/asset/id/', /asset/@id, '/version/', /asset/@version, '/storage/master/file'))"/>
        </xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:for-each select="$storage//t.classification/descendant::*[not(name()='atict:add')]">
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="./name() != 'atict:add'
                                                            and ./name() != 'atict:del'
                                                            and ./name() != 'qualifier'
                                                            and ./name() != 'temporary.class'
                                                            ">
                                <xsl:variable name="sinPeriod">
                                    <xsl:copy-of select="replace(name(), '\.', '-')"/>
                                </xsl:variable>
                                <asset_feature feature="fad:t-classifications" value_key="{$sinPeriod}"/>
                            </xsl:when>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My test environment does exactly what I wish, but the live run of the code keeps outputting 3 results instead of 2 (not an error message):

```
<asset_feature feature="fad:t-classifications" value_key="none.assigned"/>
<asset_feature feature="fad:t-classifications" value_key="analgesic.adjuncts"/>
<asset_feature feature="fad:t-classifications" value_key="atict:add"/>
```

Comment: I would suggest to push the nodes through templates where a template matching `atict:add` is empty to remove it (if that is what you want) or you ensure that your template for `t.classification//*` (perhaps a predicate `t.classification//*[not(self::atict:add)]`) performs that name change or transformation you want. It might help us if you show the result you want for your shown input sample and show us a minimal but complete stylesheet you currently have.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] not snippets of code taken out of context. Also if you get an error message, post it verbatim instead of a vague description like "keeps picking up".